# How to limit the number of times a rule can repeat in XTEXT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

My language has certain keywords which only accept values of certain length range (say, between 5 and 10 decimal numbers). This id correct:

```
KeyWord = 01234
```

This is incorrect:

```
KeyWord = 1234
```

I have a rule;

```
KeyWord:
  'KeyWord' '=' INT+;
```

How to limit the number of times INT can repeat? This would so much easier if it was a more regexp-like syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement this as a validation check instead of trying to fit this in the grammar itself. See http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_1_0/050-validation.php

This will result in better error recovery and better error messages. It even allows quick-fixes.